# How to completely stop R script in RStudio v1.3?

Tags: r, rstudio

Before upgrading to the latest RStudio (I think from `v1.2` to `v1.3`) when I needed to stop the existing chunk of code from running I would simply press `Esc` and it would completely stop.

In the updated version, it seems pressing `Esc` only stops the existing line from running. It will then move on to the next line of code, before I then need to press `Esc` again. This process repeats itself until all the lines of code have been interrupted with `Esc`.

Is there a way to stop all the back-logged lines of code from running at once, similar to the previous version of RStudio?

Comment: There are options under tools > global options > code > execution; current line / multi-line etc

Comment: thanks @user20650 but I can only an option for `ctrl+enter executes` and changing this doesn't seem to effect the impact of `Esc`.

Comment: yes, you're right. I was thinking more on when a line errors and the script keeps running and I have to press esc multiple times to try to stop it. Changing the ctlr-enter stuff stops the script keeping running. But its not what youre looking for so sorry for the noise.